# nodejs express req.session post method

Tags: node.js, post, express

i'm trying to build a simple cart in express.

```
req.session.cart.styles[req.params.a] = {
                "_id":style.id,
                "style":style.style,
                "a":style.a,
                "price":style.price,
                "desc":style.desc,
                "category":style.category,
                "color":style.colors,
                "quantity":1
             };
```

and here's my json:

```
"13123":
{
"style":"13123",
"a":"13123",
"price":2,
"desc":"askfjalsidjfalskdjflasidfjekajlsdkfj",
"img":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/views/img/asdf.jpg",
"imgs":["a","b","c"],
"category":"top",
"colors":[{"color":"red","prestock":50,"instock":10,"inactive":0},{"color":"off white","prestock":60,"instock":5,"inactive":0}],
"quantity":1}}
```

you can see that 'colors' is an array, is possible to get only one color? if i post this as is, it retunrs all the colors.

ps.

```
<form method="post" action="/style/cart/add/prestock/{{stylelist.a}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="_id">
<input type="hidden" name="style" value="style">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="a">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="price">
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="category">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">      
<input class="return" type="checkbox" name="color" value="Red">
<input class="return" type="checkbox" name="color" value="Off White">
<input class="return" type="checkbox" name="color" value="Green">
</form>
```

Comment: It is possible for multiple checkboxes to be checked, so multiple values will be returned if checked. Do you want check boxes or radio buttons ?

Comment: i want multiple values returned... Thanks!

Comment: can you help me through?

Comment: How is the json being created. If I send the form I do not get your json. I get color as array of selected values or a value depending on selection.

Comment: json is a data from the server, and yes that's what i'm trying to figure it out. i can select the color manually as @tymeJV showed me, but i'm not sure how to get the value of all the checked boxes..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reference the array index, followed by the property:

```
style.colors[0].color, //returns red from your JSON
```

Comment: oh it works on fiddle! but what if i want to get all the colors that are checked only?

Comment: Is there anything being passed to signify that the box is checked?

Comment: no not yet.. what have i posted is what i have so far.. i wasn't sure where to put my function code.. how can i accomplish this? can you please guide me?

Comment: can you help me through?